# How to prevent programs stealing focus in Mint Linux 19?

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon, window-focus

I would like to prevent programs from stealing window focus in Mint Linux 19.
I have tried changing **the "Prevent focus stealing" option** in the Windows preferences dialog (see screenshot below), but it **doesn't seem to prevent programs stealing focus**.

How do I make it *actually* work?

[image]

Comment: can you describe your issue better?  for me it is annoying when I am reading emails and click on a link in thunderbird to open a page but want to stay in thunderbird to read the next emails then go to the newly opened tabs in firefox.  as of now when i click the link it immediately jumps to firefox and i have to click back to thunderbird.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Debian with Cinnamon and this actually works:

Search for 'Windows', then:

Windows > Behaviour > Prevent focus stealing > On.

I was experiencing this issue with Thunderbird Lightning Popups and could now finally resolve this.

[image]

Comment: I don't see what was different in the answer to what failed in the question.  I have the same problem with Linux Mint 20.3 and xfce.